# Azure websites - create ftp account

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-web-app-service

I'm just created a website ("Basic" plan) under Microsoft Azure. In order to deploy my website, I created an ftp user that can upload my website code.

Additionally to this upload FTP user, I want to create **another** FTP account that will have a permission for specific directory in filesystem.

I'm search all over the Dashboard and didn't found a clue where this "create ftp account" is.

How I'm should do this?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by `I created an ftp user that can upload my website code`? are you referring to the default user that you get from Azure Websites?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, Azure only supports FTP only for deployment. And there is no way to create second ftp account for file accessing. So you'll have to come up with a different way to manage your site. What is the purpose of the second account anyway? probably there is a work-around without getting ftp involved.

Comment: According to user activity, I have a virtual machine that processing information (the result of this process is a file) and upload the result to the server with FTP. Now, I'm don't want to give this application my development keys... What if someone will hack this? I'm wish to give as minimal as needed.

Comment: You can upload the result to Azure Blob Storage and get your web-site to read from that. That would be the most logical thing to do if you are in Azure

Comment: This storage can be access from my website and virtual machine simultaneity?

Comment: Yes, Blob storage can be accessed from many different places at the same time and far better and quicker than accessing ftp server. Here is a basic tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/490178/How-to-Use-Azure-Blob-Storage-with-Azure-Web-Sites