# Second FTP account for file accessing not possible, is there a workaround?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to give a designer access to specific folders within an Azure website I have. I would like for the designer to have access via FTP. However, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24517412/azure-websites-create-ftp-account), having multiple FTP user accounts on the same Azure website is not possible and the accepted answer suggests coming up with a "different way to manage" the website. This means that if you want collaboration on an Azure website, you have to share the entire directory structure. Please correct me if I am wrong.

I know you can download the Publish Profile settings from Azure as seen on [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/ca5ba056-9d65-44a7-b4e7-91368af8cd69/support-for-multiple-ftp-users-in-the-same-azure-website?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview). This does not solve the issue as the publish profile simple gives you the FTP credentials for a specific website (instead of all of your Azure websites) but still does not provide the option to create new FTP users with limited directory permissions.

**So, my question is:** is there some way to [edit the Publish Profile settings](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/azure-web-sites-ftp-credentials) when they are downloaded so folder access is limited? If not, what methods have you used for website development collaboration on Azure where certain folders should be hidden and protected?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but have you looked into deployment via DropBox or GitHub?  That might meet your requirement of allowing designers to update their content without being able to modify anything else.

Comment: This is a good point, I am looking right now to see how this would be done specifically on GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You guys are right about using a source control system like GitHub instead of trying to provide access by creating a second FTP user.

Others have asked this question - not in the context of azure though.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418705/github-restricting-access) talks about using *submodules* on github to give a contractor access to a subfolder and all folders / files under that sub folder.

SO - I believe [linking azure to github](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/#Step7) would be necessary and then from there, [creating and managing submodules](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) from github would allow for collaboration. I believe a required aspect of this would be to have a private repo on github for the main repo. All of the files in the repo would otherwise be available for forking which would defeat the entire purpose of maintaining some discretion on access rights in the first place.

Comment: If a simpler one-off implementation without using submodules is desirable, create a repository _only_ with the files you want contractors to have access to, and link it to an existing Azure Website with all your files.  I found with bitbucket it just deploys the new files and leaves the existing files on the site untouched.  So in our scenario, contractors can only access the repository files and can't see the web.config or our dll's with the compiled source code.  I've set it up so they can just change our .ascx, .html and js files.  Works well, although obviously slower than ftp to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

For collaborative work with Azure Websites, you can enable source control. This includes tfs, git, dropbox, bitbucket, and codeplex. Dropbox is not the best collaborative tool, as it's not designed to be a version control system, but it's very convenient.

If you have a repository with any of the abovementioned providers, you can now give your designer their own account with the version control system.

Comment: I am using Git. I do not have the source code on GitHub. Would this be necessary to do what you are saying? I see there are two candidate options: [user account permissions](https://help.github.com/articles/permission-levels-for-a-user-account-repository) and [organization account permissions](https://help.github.com/articles/permission-levels-for-an-organization-repository). However - this leaves me with two questions:

1The GitHub articles mention general read/write permissions, not specific folder protection
2Doesn't giving access to the git repo files negate the purpose of hiding folders?